# What are the rules to the card game “Queenie”

Tags: identify-this-game

This is a very old game that was played by my previous generation; however no one can remember the rules and there seem to be few people who actually remember how to play it.

Comment: It would be useful to provide any details at all the you remember about it. Especially given the two answers that currently exist, is this a solitaire or multi-player game?

Answer (score 1):

It’s a simple betting game.

- All 52 cards are dealt.
- One hand to every player
  plus a ***dummy hand*** to the side.
- The ***left out card*** - The last card in the deck is not handed out or turned over until the hand is over.

Their are 2 pots:

- **First person out pot**
  The first player who have played all their cards.
- **Queenie pot**
  Who ever plays the queen that is the same suit as the left out card.

You contribute money in each pot to play the hand.
I have played $1 / $1 per pot or 25 cents / 25 cents per pot, it’s what every you want.

The goal is to:

- **Go out first** and / or,
- **Play a Queen** that matches the ***left out card***.

Before play:
The dealer has first choice to swap hand with the ***dummy hand***. If they say No it goes to next person and so on.

Most of the times you swap, if you don’t have a run on numbers or Queens.

Game play:
You start the game with 2 of spades.
The next card to be played is 3 of spades, then 4 of spades and so on. The game continues until no one has the next card in turn.

Then the person who played the last card (i.e. highest spade) plays their lowest red card. Again everyone follows suit in sequence until nobody’s can play the next card.

Then you go lowest black. You keep swapping back and forth until someone goes out.

Winning the pots:
That person (who first got rid of all their cards) gets the **First person out pot**.

Then turn over the ***left out card***. If someone played that suit's Queen, they get the **Queenie pot**.

If nobody played the Queen that pot rides. The same if nobody can go out.

Next hand:
You then repeat the above all over again, each contributing again to both pots.

Finish:
You play as long as you want or until the cash is gone.

Comment: What's "not how you play"? The question didn't specify anything to hang that statement on. If you'd like to reply to another answer, do that (but note that my answer is just quoting the rules of a game called "Queenie" on another site).

Answer (score 1):

I also remember Queenie as a two pot betting game very well. I used to play it over 40 years ago with my parents, grandparents, aunties and uncles at family get togethers, usually Christmas Day evening or New Year’s day. We played in Yorkshire, England, but the family originated in County Durham.

Rules I played by are very similar to Bonnie’s answer:

Use a standard 52 card deck. Aces are low, kings are high. Three or more players.

Each player puts a token or previously agreed standard stake into both a ‘going out’ pot and a ‘queen’ pot.

All the cards are dealt, one hand to each player, plus a dummy hand to the player to the right of the dealer. At any point during the deal, dealer places a card face down by the queen pot. Depending on the number of players, some hands may have one card more than others.

The player to the right of the dealer picks up their first hand and, without seeing the dummy hand, decides if they want to keep it or to swap it for the dummy. If not swapped, the dummy is offered in turn around the table, but now if a player decides to swap, they must buy it by paying an additional ante into the going out pot.

The player to the dealer’s right starts by playing their lowest card, if they have two cards of the same value, they can choose which to play. Play continues following suit, with the next card in sequence being played by whoever has it. The sequence stops when the king is played, or the next required card in the suit is missing (because it’s either in the discarded dummy or is the card by the queen pot).

As the first card is played in a sequence, the player announces what the card is eg. “Ace of diamonds” and subsequent cards are called out as they are played, eg. “two”; then “three and four” etc.

Played cards are placed, upturned, in a pile in front of each player, with queens separated out.

A player who ends a sequence, plays again, this time they must play their lowest card in a suit of a different colour. So for example, if the last card of a sequence is a club, the player plays their lowest diamond or heart. Again, if a player has two cards with the same value, they can choose which one to play.

If a player who plays again has cards left, but none in either suit of a different colour, they announce “No Red”, or “No Black”. Play then passes to the player on their right who must play their lowest card of the required colour.

Play continues until one player is ‘out’ by playing all their cards. They then win the going out pot. It’s possible that no-player can be ‘out’, because unplayed cards in all players hands are of the wrong colour. The going out pot then rolls over to the next game.

The queen pot card is then revealed. The pot is won by the player who has played the queen of the same suit. The queen must have been played, there is no win if it’s still in a players hand. If not won, the pot rolls over to the next game, where it’s swollen by the new antes.

The game can be played by three or more players, The more players, the faster the game, because there are less cards ‘missing’ in the dummy hand and sequences can be rattled off quite quickly.

Strategy is limited to deciding whether to swap or buy the dummy hand and choosing between two cards of the same value when starting a new sequence. Although not a frequent occurrence, this choice can be quite critical in the later stages of a game.

Hands are usually swapped because a player is seeking a queen, or because a player has several jacks (the absence of which will make it difficult for queens to be played by other players) or because the hand is unbalanced with too many cards of the same colour, or there are too many high value (non-queen) cards, either of which can make it unlikely that a player will be ‘out’. Queen-less hands are sometimes kept if they have low value card sequences which can be played all at once and thereby increase the chances of winning the ‘going out’ pot

The limited strategies make it quite a good game for levelling out age and ability, as the chance of winning doesn’t differ by too much between players. As a six and seven year old I certainly enjoyed playing with the family in a ‘grown-up’ game. It can be quite fast paced and fun too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the rules on [this page](https://solitaire.game/help/queenie):

## Queenie

Build stacks of cards in alternating colors as in Klondike, move arbitrary groups of cards as in Yukon, and deal waves of cards onto to the tableau, as in Spider.

### Objective

Place all cards on the foundation in sequence.

### Deck

One standard deck of 52 cards.

### Layout

#### Stock

- When selected, deals one card to each tableau pile.
- Only a single pass through the stock is allowed.

#### Foundation

- Four empty foundation piles.
- Any Ace may be played to any empty foundation pile.
- A card may be built on a card in a foundation pile if it is one rank higher and the same suit.
- An Ace may be played on a King, continuing the sequence.

#### Tableau

- Seven tableau piles with one card dealt to the first pile, two to the second, and so on.
- All cards are face-up.
- An empty pile may be filled with any King.
- A card may be built on a card in a tableau pile if it is one rank lower and a different color.
- Stacks of cards may be moved from a tableau pile if they are each one rank lower and a different color.